# Adding a lightbox ruins CSS

Tags: html, css, lightbox

I wanted to add a lightbox to play videos instead of redirecting to the page so user will stay on the website.

I am using the code from this: https://codepen.io/DonnaG/pen/pgHtz

I have 7 lightboxes, adding the first two is fine, but when I add the third, it ruins the css for the remaining 4.

---

Basically, there are three lightboxes in this form:

```
<section id="one" class="wrapper spotlight style4">
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="#wayhome" class="image"><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <div class="content">
            <h2 class="major">Name</h2>
            <p> Description </p>
            <a href="#wayhome" class="special">Watch the Trailer</a>
            <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="wayhome">
            <div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
                <div class="modal-header"><h3></h3></div>
                <div class="modal-body"><iframe width="870" height="489" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/231027224" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

That ruins the styling for this section:

```
<section id="four" class="wrapper alt style1">
    <div class="inner">
        <h2 class="major">Witness Me</h2>
        <p>More projects I've worked on,    from shorts to promos to documentaries.</p>
        <section class="features">
            <article>
                <a href="#natural" class="image"><img src="images/pic06.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <h3 class="major">A</h3>
                <p>B</p>
                <a href="#natural" class="special">Watch me</a>
                <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="natural">
                <div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="modal-header"><h3></h3></div>
                    <div class="modal-body"><iframe width="870" height="489" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
                <a href="#5374" class="image"><img src="images/pic07.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <h3 class="major">A</h3>
                <p>B</p>
                <a href="#5374" class="special">Watch me</a>
                <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="5374">
                <div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="modal-header"><h3></h3></div>
                    <div class="modal-body"><iframe width="870" height="489" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
                <a href="#superstore" class="image"><img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <h3 class="major">A</h3>
                <p>B</p>
                <a href="#superstore" class="special">Watch me</a>
                <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="superstore">
                <div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="modal-header"><h3></h3></div>
                    <div class="modal-body"><iframe width="870" height="489" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article>
                <a href="#pig" class="image"><img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <h3 class="major">A</h3>
                <p>B</p>
                <a href="#pig" class="special">Watch me</a>
                <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="pig">
                <div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="modal-header"><h3></h3></div>
                    <div class="modal-body"><iframe width="870" height="489" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

Any advice on how I can isolate each one so it doesn't effect the rest of the code? Removing some of those pieces of code change the form in a different way, and not having the lightboxes is obviously a choice but I like the small feature.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because .lighbox is “fixed”. I would imagine a lot of things are displaying overlapped. You should try wrapping the light boxes in containers that are positioned relative to each other.

Comment: Sorry, but can I ask how I could go about doing that? Is is possible to change .lightbox to "relative" or would that not work?

Comment: I am not sure if that would work, I am not testing your code. Try it, if it fails then it doesn’t work. You should be trying these things anyway. And I’m sorry, but I did tell you to try wrapping the light boxes in containers and positioning them relative to each other.